# Type could not be resolved in ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

In android ndk when i use the header files that is generated by helper tool `javah` it works fine. but when i create a normal file with .h extension and include `jni.h` and any other required header files i am not able use the type or keyword or any functions from the included header files and it always shows me the "Type '*whatever*' couldn't be resolved" while this same thing i can do in the machine generated header files with `javah` tools without any cause.

Though i've included arm platforms library in C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols ->Include. it keeps showing me this error.

Consider the following piece of code.

```
#include "store.h"
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#ifndef _STOREWATCHER_H_
#define _STOREWATCHER_H_

#define SLEEP_DURATION 5
#define STATE_OK 0
#define STATE_KO 1
#ifdef __cplusplus
   extern "C" {
#endif
    typedef struct{
        Store* mStore;
        JavaVM* mJavaVM;
        jobject mStoreFront;
        pthread_t mThread;
        int32_t mState;
    }StoreWatcher;
#ifdef __cplusplus
} 
#endif
#endif
```

it shows me in this code that `Store`, `JavaVM`, `jobject`, `pthread_t` couldn't be resolved. Please help me.

any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: don't know how but my problem is solved with creating a C file and including this header file into this C file. can anyone tell me how it happens or is it like i have to include this header file in any C file..?

Comment: The published piece of code is an `.h` file, isn't it?

Is your problem that including it in a `.cpp` file causes compilation error?

Did you try to remove `extern "C"` around the `struct`

Comment: @AlexCohn, yes it's a .h file. and i've tried removing extern "C" arround struct but again that wasn't helping me. but after making include of this header file in my target C file the red error line  suddenly gone disappear and then i was able to make use of all the JNI syntax in .h file.

Comment: Oh, I believe I understand what you mean... In C, unlike Java, you have files with names like `storewatcher.c` and files with names like `storewatcher.h`. The `.h` files are not compiled on themselves, you must use `#include` directive in one or more `.c` files for the `.h` file to be recognized by the compiler.

Comment: @AlexCohn, yes exactly what you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, unlike Java, you have files with names like `storewatcher.c` and files with names like `storewatcher.h`. The `.h` files are not compiled on themselves, you must use `#include` directive in one or more `.c` files for the `.h` file to be recognized by the compiler, e.g.

```
#include "storewatcher.h"
```